# Getting ipv6 subnet mask from net.CIDRMask

Tags: go, ipv6

I am working on code, and trying to add ipv6 support.  The following code is in the current code base for ipv4 support.  The code takes a ipv4 ip address and gets the subnet mask for the address on a /32.

```
// string of ip address
networkInterface["ip_address"] = v.IpAddress[0]
m := net.CIDRMask(v.IpConfig.IpAddress[0].PrefixLength, 32)
subnetMask := net.IPv4(m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3])
networkInterface["subnet_mask"] = subnetMask.String()
```

I know that `net.CIDRMask` works with ipv6, I am uncertain how to use it with an ipv6 address.

I am now testing the ip address to determine if the address is ipv4 or ipv6:

```
testInput := net.ParseIP(v.IpAddress[0])
if testInput.To4() != nil {
// find ipv4 subnet mask
}
if testInput.To16() != nil {
// do ipv6 subnet mask
}
```

The unit tests for `net.CIDRMask` have examples working with ipv6 located here: https://golang.org/src/net/ip_test.go

But it is beyond both my golang experience and ipv6 knowledge.

While RTFM'ing the docs https://golang.org/pkg/net/#CIDRMask mention:

```
func CIDRMask(ones, bits int) IPMask
```

> CIDRMask returns an IPMask consisting of `ones' 1 bits followed by 0s
>   up to a total length of `bits' bits. For a mask of this form, CIDRMask
>   is the inverse of IPMask.Size.

So what values do I use for `ones` and `bits`?

This is what is comming back from the api:

```
$ govc vm.info -json vcsa | jq .VirtualMachines[0].Guest.Net[0].IpConfig.IpAddress [   {
    "IpAddress": "10.20.128.218",
    "PrefixLength": 22,
    "Origin": "",
    "State": "preferred",
    "Lifetime": null   } ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `bits` is 128 for IPv6, and 32 for IPv4.  For `ones`, it depends, it's not 100% clear what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to get the subnet mask of the CIDR that represents that 1 single IP?  If so, then `ones` should equal `bits`.  Furthermore, if you're always going to be calling the function with the same two pairs of inputs, why not just do them once, up front?

Comment: I am trying to get a subnet mask for a single ip address.  Let me be more clear... I think that is what the code is doing.  Newbie to golang :)

Comment: The subnet mask for any single IPv4 address will always be what you see on line 307 here: https://golang.org/src/net/ip_test.go#L307.  For IPv6, it will always be what you see on line 311: https://golang.org/src/net/ip_test.go#L311.

Comment: So I should not recalculate it, create a constant and reuse it.  But now I am quite confused.  Is the code even doing what it is intending to do?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your code is doing because you haven't provided a minimal example that can run.  I don't know what `v` is, or what `v.IpConfig.IpAddress[0].PrefixLength` tends to be, but if the latter is 32, then yes, it does what you want.

Comment: So it looks like ones should be the prefix length as before. Updated question. @AmitKumarGupta can you add an answer so I can give you some answered questions love?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `PrefixLength` is, it may be some field defined in one of your structs, but it doesn't appear to be a field on anything in the `net` package, or in fact anywhere in the standard library: https://golang.org/search?q=PrefixLength.

So I'm not sure what `PrefixLength` is expected to give, but, I can tell you:

- IPv4 addresses consist of 32 bits of data (256 x 256 x 256 x 256 total IPs), so when dealing with IPv4, the value for the `bits` argument to `net.CIDRMask` should be 32.
- IPv4 addresses have 128 bits of data, so the `bits` argument is 128.
- The subnet mask for a CIDR range corresponding to a single IP will have the maximum number of ones, so the `ones` value is 32 or 128, depending on whether you're talking IPv4 or IPv6.

Therefore, for IPv4, you should call `net.CIDRMask(32, 32)`, and for IPv6, `net.CIDRMask(128, 128)`.  Since these will be the exact same calculations every time, you have the option to simply set the values up front as constants in your code.  The correct values are:

- For IPv4: https://golang.org/src/net/ip_test.go#L307
- For IPv6: https://golang.org/src/net/ip_test.go#L311

Comment: PrefixLength is the value that I will use for `ones`, and is coming back from the govc api call, the json is above.